# Transfer Functions in xtk

Tags: xtk, ami.js

How would I go about plugging in a transfer function to determine coloring and opacity in xtk based on pixel scalar intensity and / or gradient magnitude. This may be a separable 1d transfer Functions or a [2d transfer function](https://blog.kitware.com/2d-transfer-function-support-in-gpuvolumemapper/). In addition to VTK, [ImageVis3D](http://www.sci.utah.edu/software/145-news/software-news-cibc/352-iv3d-2-0.html) also supports this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in support in XTK for that and is most likely not gonna happen.

We recommend using [`ami.js`](https://github.com/FNNDSC/ami) - there is no built-in support for 2D transfer functions in in `ami.js` yet but it is under active development and should provide most of required functionalities to support this feature.

Hope that helps -